# Android - spin + symbol in textView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `textView` as '+' sign at the end of the horizontal layout. When I press the textView I need the plus symbol to rotate at the same axis. I have this `rotate.xml` file.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"/>
```

But this makes my plus to go around. Help me to spin my textView in the same axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to set Xscale & Yscale property just for rotation

If you want to rotate "+" from center then pivot should be "50%"

This is my working code you can try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Comment: It's working.... I did a mistake by adding padding to my view... Now it's layout_margin... And it works perfect...